# Webpack/react hot reload reloading whole page?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

This is probably asked all the time, but I've tried every approach under the sun and can't find a solution.

[I've created a repo to make it easier to get help](https://github.com/enrique-ramirez/help). You can clone it, run `npm install` and then `npm start:dev` to see a quick local server on http://localhost:8080.

It works, and when I change a file (say, `src/components/Note/Note.css`) the app does reload. However, I want to only reload the component, not the whole page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To debug issues like this, enable "Preserve log" in Chrome DevTools console settings to preserve console log across page refresh.

The error was:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This was fixed once the following changes were made:

1. Remove `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` from plugins (as webpack-dev-server is started with `--hot`)
2. Also opt-out of babel transpiling ES6 modules by updating `presets` in `.babelrc` to `["react", ["env", { "modules": false }]]`.

`"modules": false` is to tell babel to not compile import/exports and let webpack handle it as described [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#mixing-es2015-with-amd-and-commonjs) and [here](https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/) (Check step 3.3.c).

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

THANK YOU!!

Comment: Quick question: why do I need to opt-out of babel transpiling ES6 modules?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: How to solve this in 2020? I can't find these options in create-react-app project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/):

If you edit a file in `pages/`, the whole page will reload. Bummer, state is lost.

If you edit a file in `components/`, only the relevant module will re-load (i.e., hot reload as you expect).

My recommendation: keep the files in your `pages/` folder simple.
Iterate your design/details in a component file in the `components/` folder.

For example:

```
// pages/welcome.jsx
import WelcomePage from "../components/welcomePage";

export default function Welcome() {
  return <WelcomePage />;
}
```

```js
// components/welcomePage.jsx
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./layout";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PlayerContext from "../../context/playerContext";

export default function WelcomePage() {
  const { songTitle } = useContext(PlayerContext);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="...">
        <div className="...">
          Welcome! Let's play {songTitle}.
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Then you can go ahead and make small edits to `components/welcomePage.jsx` without losing state in your browser.